# showing error [symbol.iterator()] in ts generics in knex query

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, types, knex.js

```
const [user]: T = await db("users").insert(data).returning("*");
// error:Type 'T' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.
```

My knex query typescript giving me error when i tried brackets in knex query to return single object from array.Can someone help me understand to why it is showing me this error even when i passed specific generic type and "user" variable is storing a single object as specified by type.Is there any go through from it, I also tried with .first() instead of square brackets but it shows a different error then.

```
const user: T = await db("users").insert(data).first().returning("*");

//error: Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'T'.
//  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'any[]'.
```

Comment: You're probably looking for `const [user]: [T] = await …`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the .first(). Not sure it works well together with the returning().
Since it will be returning an array in ALL cases, you may as well do `T[]`. It should accept it.

```
const user: T[] = await db("users").insert(data).returning("*");
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Simply do:

```
const user: T = await db("users").select("*").first();
```

`.returning()` is for inserts, updates, and deletes, not selects.

Comment: thanks michel for this one, can u plz suggest me a way through for inserts, update mutations too?

Comment: edited my question accordingly to mutations